# Is there any other mathematical tool to measure velocity, instead useing derivative?

Tags: velocity, differentiation

To measure [velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity) we use derivative

$$v=\frac {dr}{dt}.$$

Is the any other mathematical tool to do this?.

Comment: The derivate is not the way to measure velocity, it's the definition.

Comment: You could do $v=\int a dt$

Comment: The average velocity in some time period $\Delta t$ is $v_\mathrm{ave} = \frac{\Delta r}{\Delta t}$.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, the mathematical definition of (instantaneous) velocity is usually taken to be the derivative of position, though other mathematical definitions are possible.  In particular, for one dimensional motion (motion along a straight line, say the x-axis), velocity at a given moment can be defined as the slope of the [tangent line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent#Tangent_line_to_a_curve) of the position versus time graph at that moment.  From a purely mathematical point of view this is the long way around in that derivatives are commonly used to define tangent lines.  However, it is possible (but tricky) to define tangent lines geometrically as the unique line that *locally* only touches the curve at the point of interest.  But making this rigorous soon leads to such issues as needing to restrict the class of curves allowed, with smooth curves an obvious choice, thus getting you back to calculus.

[image: Tangent Line to a Curve for a Point Sliding Along the Curve]

---

Also, for one dimensional motion one can define (instantaneous) velocity as the (instantaneous) rate at which position is changing with respect to time.  But like tangent lines, [instantaneous rates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_(mathematics)) are usually defined using derivatives.

Comment: Nice animation :)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be approaching this from a very narrow definition of doing physics. If you are given a function form for position depending on time, then sure, velocity is *defined* to be the derivative, so you may as well take it. If there were any other tool that did this, it would be identical to differentiation, and hence there can be no other tool.

But who ever said physics has to start with a table of position values? Sometimes you measure velocity directly, like when Doppler shifts are involved. Sometimes you start with known forces, in which case you divide by the mass and integrate to get velocity. The list goes on...

Answer (score 0):

This definition imposes itself; I don't understand why are you searching for "another way to calculate the velocity"? The velocity is defined to be the derivative.

I'm supposing you want to calculate and not measure the velocity using indirect methods like the Doppler effect